# jQuery else Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to have an whole page overlay, when mega menu is active. Curretly the function adds .show class to the overlay div, but it does not remove using the "else" function. Here is what I have:

HMTL:

```
<header>
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <ul class="mega-sub-menu"></ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</header>

<div id="twc-page-overlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#twc-page-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
    z-index: 50;
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
  $("div").click(function(){
    if ( $('.mega-menu-item').hasClass('mega-toggle-on') ) {
      $('#twc-page-overlay').addClass('show');
    }
    else {
      $('#twc-page-overlay').removeClass('show');
    }
  });
});
```

Any help you be much appreciate!
Thanks!

Comment: Where is `.mega-menu-item` in your code? You are checking for class `mega-toggle-on`, but your code does not set oder remove this class anywhere, so the `if` does the same all the time.

Comment: Just to notice, `else` statement is from JavaScript and not jQuery, it's just a inclusion.

Comment: Marcio, what are you trying to do? You're trying to toggle the display of `#twc-page-overlay` when you click on `.mega-menu-item`?

Comment: Check for errors in the console and say if there's one.

Comment: Andrei, yes! Trying to display #twc-page-overlay when the mega menu is displayed.

Comment: And when is the `mega-menu` displayed? How are you showing it? Do you click a button or just hover?

Comment: hover. Look: http://clients.fariadesign.com/thewavecollection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all `.show` does is toggle display of your element, you don't need it. <kbd>[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)</kbd> will toggle `display` from `none` to `block`:

```js
$("#toggleOverlay").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#twc-page-overlay').toggle();
})
```

```css
#twc-page-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 50;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="toggleOverlay" style="margin: 20px;">Toggle Overlay</a>

<div id="twc-page-overlay"></div>
```

Clarification: There is no "native" jQuery way of binding the display of an element to the presence of a class or not. However, if you display your mega menu on a `hover` you can use <kbd>[.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)</kbd> method, like this:

```js
$("#toggleOverlay").hover(function(e){
  $('#twc-page-overlay').show();
}, function(e){
  $('#twc-page-overlay').hide();
})
```

```css
#twc-page-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 50;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="toggleOverlay" style="margin: 20px;">Toggle Overlay</a>

<div id="twc-page-overlay"></div>
```

Ok, based on your website, this should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("li.mega-menu-item-has-children").hover(
    function(){
    $('#twc-page-overlay').show();
  }, function(){
    $('#twc-page-overlay').hide();
  })
});
```

Comment: Yes! Can #toggleOverlay be a class?

Comment: How are you showing the mega menu? How are you adding that class? You need to bind the toggle on whatever event is showing/hiding your mega menu. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: This is crazy.. still not working.. I have tried everything

Comment: is this right? : `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  


$(".mega-menu-item").hover(function(e){
  $('#twc-page-overlay').show();
}, function(e){
  $('#twc-page-overlay').hide();
});



});`

Comment: Try the updated script in answer. It should work on hover now. I thought you displayed the mega-menu on click. Hover is not very mobile friendly... How do you hover on a mobile phone?

Comment: I changed to hover. Still not working, either with click or hover. This is crazy

Comment: I will do something else with mobile.. i just need to get this desktop finish first

Comment: It's working for me. Just change the selector from `$('li.mega-menu-item')` to `$('li.mega-menu-item-has-children')`, so it doesn't show the overlay on the menu items that don't actually have a mega menu (like "our story"). Updated answer.

Comment: Your updated answer doesnt work... whats working is: `$(".mega-menu-link").on('hover', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#twc-page-overlay').show();
})
$("body").on('hover', '#twc-page-overlay, #header-holder', function(e){
  $('#twc-page-overlay').hide();
})`

Comment: when I change to mega-menu-item-has-children , it doesnt work either

Comment: I believe the reason it didn't work was because it needed to be wrapped in a jQuery wrapper. I updated the answer. I've tested it on your website (using console) and it works. But I can't properly test it because some other script is also interfering with the same elements. (Probably the old version of this one :) )

Answer (score 0):

You never change the meta-toggle-on class on .mega-menu-item. Therefore, your if statement will always be true, even when executed multiple times

Answer (score 0):

May you can use toggle ?

```
.toggleClass('active');
```

If you wanna toggle it:

```
.toggle();
```

Comment: I tried to used this before and didnt work. Maybe I didnt use the right way. how it would be the complete code?

Comment: $('ur-element').click(function () {

        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).toggle();
        
    });

Beside using $(this) you can use as $('which-element-u-want')

Comment: Marcio In which condition you want your div will shown ? Give some more info then I can write the all code for you.

Comment: When li.mega-menu-item-has-children is hover